# http auto link script doesnt work on bootstrap div

Tags: javascript

I am making autolink script with bootstrap div

```
text = text.replace(/((http:|https:)\/\/[\x21-\x26\x28-\x7e]+)/gi, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");


item.addClass('well well-small')
    .append($('<div/>').text(text))
    .children('div').children('i').after(username);
```

href link is not available in this DIV.

bootstrap has function to unvalid the link tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `.html` instead of `.text`

```
.append($('<div/>').html(text))
```